# How to call views in a "master" view with xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

**Hello everyone**,

Today, i'm trying to start developping an Ipad application, i'm new on it. I did a scheme of my application with a program and i'd like to implement it with xcode.

My application would be split in 2 main parts -> first : a form with a set of buttons and second : the result.

What i'd like to know is, if it's possible to create a "master" view with the form for example and everytime i'd press a button from my form, if it would be possible to call the "result" view in my master view.

Thank you for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a new project and choose `Master-Detail Application` as your template, so Xcode will generate some code for you to look in to. Once you understand how it all works, you can decide to throw stuff out and create something better than the template.